# Is there any case in English where a noun phrase is not the subject of a sentence, or a complement of a verb, or the object of a preposition?

Tags: syntax, english

It's a simple question but limited to how *noun phrases* function in English sentences.

Time phrases like *last week*, are an example of noun phrases functioning adverbially but they are still verb complements.

Comment: _She is **a beautiful woman**_. Here "a beautiful woman" is a predicative complement.

Comment: With predicative complements and adverbial phrases, you’ve more or less exhausted the possible roles there are to play… I suppose you could add interjections (“God! Idiot!”).

Comment: _**My friends**, I feel tired doing someone's easy homework, so I'm leaving._

Comment: It's also limited to English, I would suppose. Otherwise, billions  of examples come to mind.

Comment: Appositives, vocatives, extraposed clauses, demonstratives with gestures, dummy pronouns, ... That's about all I can think of. Degenerate cases, most of them, rather like prepositions are degenerate cases of noun cases.

Comment: Modifier, complement in NP structure, determiner, supplement and vocative come to mind

Comment: @YellowSky: a predicative complement is a refined term for a verb complement, but it is still a vc. "My friends," is a good example, vocative. :)

Comment: One must distinguish between predicate noun phrases (like _She's a doctor_ and _He's the father of her children_) and verbal complement clauses (like the infinitive in _She wants Mike to fix the shed_ and the gerund in _Mike enjoys fixing things_). Calling something "a predicative complement" muddies the waters considerably.

Comment: I don't see problem with 'predicative complement', since PCs only occur with certain verb such as "be", "seem" and the like, and they require a predicand.

Comment: @UbuEnglish To say that "a predicative complement is a refined term for a verb complement, but it is still a vc" is misleading, since verbs can take different kinds of complement, not just PCs. Compare "Ed is a teacher" (PC) vs "Ed informed me that he was a teacher" (content clause as comp of verb).

Comment: @BillJ: Misleading? That's pretty strong language, Bill. Who is it misleading to exactly? For the purpose of this question, a verb complement is a verb complement. Not making a distinction that is subsumed by another more general one is not misleading; it's concise. Also, I wasn't even talking to you.

Comment: What are you talking about? This is an open forum. It's _potentially_ misleading because it implies that all complements of verbs are predicative, which they're not. I gave you examples. Incidentally, your original question contains an error, where it says that "noun phrases functioning adverbially but they are still a verb complements". A noun phrase (or any phrase) cannot be both complement and adverbial, since they are quite different functions. In "I saw her last week", the NP "last week" is a temporal adjunct used deictically, not a verb complement.

Comment: This isn't passion, it's belligerence.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Noun phrases can occur in an adnominal '-s genitive construction:

> *[the Queen of England]'s hat*

Rarely, noun phrases can occur as the complement of [certain unusual adjectives](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3096):

> *it was worth [the long wait in line]*

> *conduct unbecoming [a good citizen]*

None of the bracketed noun phrases ("the Queen of England('s)", "the long wait in line", and "a good citizen") is the subject of a sentence, the complement of a verb, or the object of a preposition.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer.